# AutoHotKey SendInput only once

Tags: autohotkey

Hello i'm making a program that disables mic,speakers and camera. But When i press the 'o' button program pressing tab and space button non stop. I want the program to run only once when the key is pressed.

The Code:

```
~*o::
SoundSet, +1, MASTER, mute,3 
SoundGet, master_mute, , mute, 3
ToolTip, Mute %master_mute% 
SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, 3000 
send {Volume_Mute}

RemoveToolTip: 
ToolTip
SendInput, {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab Up} 
SendInput, {Space}{Space Up}
Click, A_ScreenWidth/2, A_ScreenHeight/2
return

#x::Reload
```